# Transformation Definition

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, transformation

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices that have no eigenvalues in common. Let $T$ be the transformation $$
  T(S):=AS-SB
$$ that maps the $n\times n$ matrices, $M_n$, to the $M_n$.

Can we assume that $AS=SB$?

Comment: Why would you think so?

Comment: @JohnD [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044472/invertibility-of-linear-transformation)

Comment: From your link, it seems that the relevant question is whether $AS=SB$ implies that $S=0$. This is quite different from _assuming_ that $AS=SB$.

Comment: The fact that Robert Israel proves in his answer is that **if** $AS = SB$ (that is, **if** $T(S) = 0$), then $S = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you assume $AS=SB$, then $T(S)$ is a zero map for all $S$. This cannot happen if $A, B$ have no common eigenvalues.