# Linear Transformation Map with eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $S$ and $T$ be two $n \times n$ matrices that have no eigenvalues in common.  Show that the transformation $\Phi$ that maps the $n\times n$ matrices, $M_n$, to the $M_n$ and is defined by the formula 
$\Phi(A):=SA - AT $ is invertible.

Comment: We had this [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044472/invertibility-of-linear-transformation).

Comment: Note that if $\Phi$ is not invertible, then there is some $A$ such that $SA = AT$. Then this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series shows that $S,T$ have a common eigenvalue.